# Download a file with a read-only lock using an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a temporary link to download text files (jQuery and Javascript) from the server and I'm using the attribute `download` in `<a>`. I'm using the method `Response.Write` to send the content to the client. I have tried modifying the server side method so that I can create a read-only lock on the file. How do I do that?

Comment: You want it to be read-only on the machine which the file has been downloaded on? If so I wouldn't bother because if you find a way to apply the lock then the user can just remove it with a right click anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to do. I do still think that there's a point in doing this because then the end user will immediately realize that he or she should not edit the file (even though it's possible to do so by removing the lock first).

Comment: if you zip the file then that will preserve read-only flag.

Comment: A zip file? Hmm, OK. I can consider doing that actually. Maybe it will not be a problem for me to store the data in such an archive. Thank you for the advice!